# Apps with EntityFrameworkCore.SQlite not running on select machines

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I've found something interesting that I can't quite seem to find the solution for.

A few applications I've built use a SQLite database with Entity Framework Core. These apps seems to only work on select machines, and clients have had issues getting them to run.

On all of my personal machines, the apps seem to run without issue, but clients have had mixed results, with most having the app boot right up and others not seeing any interface come up.

The only programs that seem to have this issue are those that incorporate EF Core and SQlite, though I can't recall having to install anything for these on my own PC.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Programs have been built with .NET Core 3.0 with EF Core 5.0.4